# How to edit data from the joined table in TDataSet

Tags: sql, delphi, dataset, dbgrid

Let's say i have 1 query, 1 main table and 2 left joins. Query looks like (for example)

```
SELECT "E.name", 
       D."title" 
  FROM "Employees" AS E 
       LEFT JOIN "Department" AS D 
            ON E."depid" = D."id_dep"
```

So now i want to change the information directly in the DBGrid. I put dataset into Edit mode, but as a result i can only edit columns which refers to Employees table, and not Department.

I know, that this method is not very correct, it would be easier and more correct to use UPDATE request, but this is a requirment of the customer. Thank you for reply

Comment: you can use http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_the_BDE_to_Cache_Updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of one query you should use two datasets with *Master-Detail Relationship* to work on each dataset (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

The documentation will guide you on how to [Creating Master-Detail Relationships](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Master-Detail_Relationships)